# How do I jump to a line number in Safari 6 Web Inspector?

Tags: safari, development, javascript

So I'm working on some javascript and I want to set a breakpoint on the line that I'm working on. It seems reasonable that I should be able to go into the Javascript debugger and jump to that line number without having to scroll to it manually.

I have read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/) and have tried a few logical guesses but there doesn't appear to be a keyboard shortcut to jump to a line number. I can't believe that this would have been missed. Is there a way to jump to a line number?

Comment: I would think so, though I can't seem to find it. Chrome has it, so I assume Safari has it. Did you try Command + L?

Comment: ⌘L seems to focus the location bar :(

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcut for this is <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in recent versions of Safari. You can find a list of keyboard shortcuts here: https://webkit.org/web-inspector/keyboard-shortcuts/.